# How to add validation in my own module?

Tags: cms, module

I select the document type from the select option then upload the file so how to validate in the code

```
<form name="file_up_form" method="post" name="fileupload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="field_container1 thumbnail span3">
        <label for="select_option">Select option here</label>
        <select name="doc_type" id="select_option" style="width: 200px;" multiple>
            <option value="1">Education</option>
            <option value="2">Certification</option>
            <option value="3">Client Paperwork</option>
            <option value="4">Invoice</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="field_container thumbnail span4">
        <label for="file">Upload here: </label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="check" value="1">
</form>
```

Here is the validation code I'm using so far:

```
<script> 
    function validate() 
    { 
        if(document.fileupload.doc_type.value == "" && document.fileupload.doc_type.value == null) 
        { 
            alert( "Please provide your document!" ); 
            return false; 
        } 
        if(document.fileupload.file.value == "" && document.fileupload.file.value == null) 
        {   
            alert( "Please provide your file!" ); 
            return false; 
        } 
        return true; 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything of your own? Have you looked at other modules to see how they do it? I Assume you have a helper.php file so you can detect the forum submission and add you validation in there

Comment: Thanks your response friend.i using normal javascript code this code working but con't raise alert message?..<script>
  function validate()
  {
     if(document.fileupload.doc_type.value == "" && document.fileupload.doc_type.value == null)
     {
       alert( "Please provide your document!" );
       return false;
     }
     if(document.fileupload.file.value == "" && document.fileupload.file.value == null)
     {
       alert( "Please provide your file!" );
       return false;
     }
     return true;
  }
 </script>

Comment: Remove `return false;` from your code. Also make sure you use the browser console to check for any error that may be given

Answer (score 3):

Change `document.fileupload.doc_type.value` to `document.getElementById('file').value`. Also, you're checking if the value is `""` AND `null`, I'm not sure if that is possible.

Unless you need to verify the file format etc., try something simpler like this:

**HTML**

```
<form onsubmit="return(validate());" name="file_up_form" method="post" name="fileupload" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <div class="field_container1 thumbnail span3">
        <label for="select_option">Select option here</label>
        <select name="doc_type" id="select_option" style="width: 200px;" multiple>
            <option value="1">Education</option>
            <option value="2">Certification</option>
            <option value="3">Client Paperwork</option>
            <option value="4">Invoice</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="field_container thumbnail span4">
        <label for="file">Upload here: </label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="check" value="1">
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script> 
    function validate() 
    { 
        if(!document.getElementById('file').value) 
        { 
            alert( "Please provide your document!" ); 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 
</script>
```

Shouldn't you also return `false` (not `true` as you currently do) if no file is selected to stop the form from being submitted? The `<form>` tag should probably include an `action` parameter too.